# Scraping data from an interactive chart

Tags: javascript, svg, web-scraping, charts, screen-scraping

I am trying to retrieve data which is generating a chart in javascript on this page:

https://www.energy-charts.de/price.htm

I found the SVG elements which draw the lines with their `M` and `L` elements, but I don't know where to start looking for the javascript array which holds the actual data. (I am assuming there must be an array somewhere).

I am thankful for any tipps and hints where I need to start looking for this data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short Answer**

The data is stored in a JSON file at https://www.energy-charts.de/price/week_2019_21.json

---

**Long Answer**

If you open developer tools (F12), you can see a load of `console.log`s from the file `price.js`. Most of them are of no use, but the line `got chartTitle from JSON! _chartTitle: Electricity production and spot prices in Germany in week 21 2019` looks like it could be of use to us.

Opening up `price.js` and searching for "got chartTitle", I found a function named `createChart`, which appears to be loading JSON files. I am assuming these will be returned from an API of some sort and not stored directly in JS files.

Scrolling up from "got chartTitle", I noticed this line: 
`d3.json(filepath, function(error, json) {`. To me, this is loading JSON from a file path. Searching for "filepath", I found it declared as a global variable. Typing this into the javascript console I see that the value is "./price/week_2019_21.json", so navigating to that URL (https://www.energy-charts.de/price/week_2019_21.json) should be the data you are looking for!

This URL is calculated in the following code block:

```
if(defaultweek < 10){
  filepath = "./price/week_" + defaultyear +"_0"+ defaultweek +".json"; //default file on first-load
}
else{
  filepath = "./price/week_" + defaultyear +"_"+ defaultweek +".json"; //default file on first-load
}
```

The default values are set in `energy-charts_default.js`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Nicely explained answer there +